# how to install license to Xen server 7.6

Tags: xenserver, hypervisor

Is it possible to activate Xen server using the trial license(90days)? I have installed xen license server using Citrix License Server Virtual Appliance. And uploaded my trial license file to local license server.

But it's giving following error. [image]

what's wrong with this?

Comment: Hi, appliance nic in the management network?

Comment: @yagmoth555 yes, they are in same local network.

Comment: It is possible. The "license instance" must be the same as the DNS name of the license server to properly assign the license. You can check this link:
https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/xenserver/7-5/downloads/installation-guide.pdf page 7-10 (mechanism for 7.6 is the same).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure whether the licensing appliance is compatible with XS 7.6, on the download webpage, they are not listening version 7.6 as compatible edition....